# Apex Rest - Api error handling HTTP status codes

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest, sfrestrequest

I am trying to handle multiple error codes in my REST service. Can anyone guide me if I am doing this correctly.

```
 try {
              if(Limits.getDmlRows() < Limits.getLimitDmlRows()){
              upsert DataUpdate;  
              }
              else if((Limits.getDmlRows() >= Limits.getLimitDmlRows()))
              {
                  RestContext.response.statusCode = 439;
                  ErrorReturn[] err = new ErrorReturn[]{ 
                  new ErrorReturn(DataUpdate.Id, 'Too many DML operations', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId + ': ' + e.getMessage())
                };
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                break;
              }
            }

            catch(System.CalloutException e){
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
                RestContext.response.statusCode = 403;
                ErrorReturn[] err = new ErrorReturn[]{ 
                    new ErrorReturn(DataUpdate.Id, 'Forbidden', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId + ': ' + e.getMessage())
                };
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                break;
            }
             catch(System.QueryException e){
                 System.debug(e.getMessage());
                RestContext.response.statusCode = 404;
                ErrorReturn[] err = new ErrorReturn[]{ 
                    new ErrorReturn(DataUpdate.Id, 'ID not found', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId + ': ' + e.getMessage())
                };
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                break;
             }

             catch(System.StringException e) {
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
                RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
                ErrorReturn[] err = new ErrorReturn[]{ 
                    new ErrorReturn(DataUpdate.Id, 'Bad Request', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId + ': ' + e.getMessage())
                };
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                break;
            }

             catch(Exception e) {
              // VALIDATION_EXCEPTION 
                if(e.getMessage().indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION') >= 0) {
                    RestContext.response.statusCode = 407;
                    ErrorReturn[] err = new ErrorReturn[]{ 
                        new ErrorReturn(DataUpdate.Id, 'Conflict Error', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId + ': ' + e.getMessage())
                };
                } else {
                    RestContext.response.statusCode = 500;
                    ErrorReturn[] err = new ErrorReturn[]{ 
                        new ErrorReturn(DataUpdate.Id, 'Internal Server Error', 'Error updating MessageID ' + msg.MessageId + ': ' + e.getMessage())
                    };
                }
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(err));
                RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                break;
            }
```

Can some one guide me on how to handle 407, 439 and 403? The caller  of my service will either reprocess or discard the record being sent based on the error code returned. I just kept CalloutException as a placeholder for the time being till I find the correct solution.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. This error-handling code is very repetitive, and seems misguided to me. (It's also unnecessary - you will not get a `CalloutException` or `QueryException` from an `upsert` DML). What is the caller of your service doing with the return status? Does it really need to know the details of a "too many DML operations" failure? How exactly does an HTTP 403 express that a callout failed, for some unknown reason?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to tell us more about what you are struggling with and where you're trying to get to with this code?

Comment: @DavidReed Which built-in exception do you think I can use to handle 403 and 404? We are thinking of handling most of the error codes that could possibly be encountered and the details are required so that the caller can handle the error accordingly from their side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to me to approach this issue backwards. You have in hand a list of HTTP status codes and are trying to find Apex exceptions that correspond to ("handle") them.

But there are scores of HTTP status codes, and most of them are either (a) completely irrelevant to this code or (b) handled by the underlying Salesforce application. For example, requests that fail to authenticate, don't deserialize properly (assuming you're letting the platform handle deserialization, as is preferred), or are otherwise nonsensical will receive an HTTP error from Salesforce itself, before your code is invoked and outside your control.

The salient question to me is "what errors can *this specific code* encounter, and how should they be communicated to the client?" There's only one actual exception the code within your `try` block can throw and which is catchable: `DMLException`. You *cannot* receive `CalloutException`, `QueryException`, or `StringException`. Should a `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` message occur, it will be a `DMLException`, so you do not need separate handling in a generic `catch` block for it.

Based on your question, the remote caller only needs an answer to one question: should I retry or should I not? `DMLException`, barring some edge cases, usually is not recoverable and should not be retried without alterations. To me, that's all you need to communicate to the caller, unless there's significant additional complexity you've not shown here. The only route I see that could lead to a retry would be an `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` message, which is usually transitory, but I would not build logic for that case unless I knew that it was a likely occurrence.

The only other relevant error appears to be the situation where you have exceeded your DML limits. But unless there is more code with more DML operations above this block, this is impossible: an API call is a single transaction, coming with its associated 150 DML operation limit. You should be able to guarantee that you will not hit this limit within the context of a single API call. (I think you probably wanted *429 Too Many Requests* for this error, by the way).